# Why data binding is not working with PropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am new to XAML and Windows 8 phone development and learning about data binding. [Here](http://wpftutorial.net/DataBindingOverview.html), it is suggested that I need to use,

```
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
```

But when I try to use it in my xaml, it is giving error as 'Requested value 'PropertyChanged' not found.' Instead it is working correctly with,

```
UpdateSourceTrigger=Default
```

I am doing something wrong, or it is deprecated in newer versions.

My code sample,

```
 <TextBox x:Name="txt1" Height="100" Width="100"></TextBox>

 <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" x:Name="txt2" Height="100" Width="100" 
    Text="{Binding Text,ElementName=txt1,
 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Windows Phone uses [XAML for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc189036(v=vs.105).aspx). That is another taste of `XAML` than WPF uses. I therefore replaced the wpf tag by the xaml tag.

Comment: @venerik Thanks, means again specific and typical way to write XAML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is not supported in Windows Phone XAML.

You can use `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` instead,
and handle the source updating in the code behind:

```
private void OnTextBoxTextChanged( object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e )
{
  TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
  BindingExpression bindingExpr = textBox.GetBindingExpression( TextBox.TextProperty );
  bindingExpr.UpdateSource();
}
```

Another alternative would be to use [Coding4Fun's library](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) BindingHelper. in that case, the syntax would be:

```
<TextBox   
  Text="{Binding FooBar, Mode=TwoWay}" 
  local:TextBinding.UpdateSourceOnChange="True" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The UpdateSourceTrigger has nothing to do with the update of the target control. Instead, it is useful when you perform some validation of a TextBox, for instance.

If you have a (view)model behind the XAML code, you should add the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and implement it as the guidelines teach.

Here is an example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41817/Implementing-INotifyPropertyChanged

The XAML snippet should work, at least for WPF. What is not working?

Comment: Control to control data binding is not working in pasted code.

Comment: I've just tested for WPF, and works fine, as expected. I can't test for WP8, though.